# Django==3.0.7 FileNotFoundError

Tags: django, python-3.x

I know that no is the best way. But I want to know why not find the file. 
The path is ok. I dont understand that.

[image]

My views.py and urls.py:
[image]

[image]

The archives path:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you need to be more explicit in where the file exists:

```
def index(request):
    file_path = f"{settings.ROOT_DIR}/templates/index.html"
    archivo = open(file_path)
    template = Template(archivo.read())
    #[... continue]
```

Comment: Hi @Ben:
IDE error: `Unresolved reference 'settings'` .
That must be in settings.py?

Comment: I find the solution with a absolute path...
`file_path = f"C:/Users/cainu/PycharmProjects/projecto1/templates/index.html"`
rules!!
Thanks

Comment: @FernandoLópez you can import settings using: `from django.conf import settings`

Comment: No works that: `Request Method: GET
Request URL: http://127.0.0.1:8000/index/
Django Version: 3.0.7
Exception Type: AttributeError
Exception Value: 
'Settings' object has no attribute 'ROOT_DIR'`

Comment: add `ROOT_DIR = environ.Path(__file__) - 3` to your settings file

Comment: Excuse me how clumsy I am with Django.
I have several questions:
environ is a library to have environment vars, true?
What the `-3` means in the command?.
I work in Windows and I have to change the direction of the bars, since it gives me the error
`No such file or directory: 'C: \\ Users \\ cainu \\ PycharmProjects / templates / index.html`. 
How I do that?
and the last question:
What are the benefits of doing this like this?